# Getting java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException while sending mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am getting a *stringOutofBoundexception* when trying to send an e-mail via gmail using JavaMail version 1.6.0

Debug details are:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.6.0
DEBUG: getProvider() returning 
javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
```

Error Details:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: -1     at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:289)
>     at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2160)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:726)
>     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)     at
>   sendEmail.main(sendEmail.java:50)

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
public class sendEmail  extends Authenticator  
{  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException{ 



String  d_email = "oracle.ossa.qa@gmail.com",
        d_uname = "oracle.ossa.qa@gmail.com",
        d_password = "mypass",
        d_host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        d_port  = "465", //465,587
        m_to = "oracle.ossa.qa@gmail.com",
        m_subject = "OPEN BUGS";
  String m_text = "text";

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.user", d_email);
props.put("mail.smtp.host", d_host);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", d_port);
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
//props.put("mail.verbose",true);

props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.put("mail.smtp.proxy.host","http://www-proxy-hqdc.us.oracle.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.proxy.port","80");

//Authenticator auth = new Authenticator();
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication  getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(d_email, "oracle@ossa");
    }
  });
session.setDebug(true);

MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

try {
    msg.setSubject(m_subject);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(d_email));
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(m_to));

Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(d_host, Integer.valueOf(d_port), d_uname, d_password);
        transport.send(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();

    } catch (AddressException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //return false;
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       // return false;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Please check your `mail.smtp.proxy.host` property. Since this is an smtp proxy, it should probably be not be routed via http. But i also checked the source code of the `SocketFetcher` and there seems to be a problem whenever a `:` is inside of the proxy host.

Answer (score 0):

Per https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html, `mail.smtp.proxy.host` is a host name only, specifying a protocol (e.g. `http://`) is not expected.

Comment: I tried without giving http ://,however I faced the below error   javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 80, response: -1

Comment: Wait are you trying to use a WEB proxy for SMTP?

Comment: I used 587 port its wrking